# Can I move a specific group of folders in one directory to a whole different directory, while being in a parent directory several levels up

Tags: command-line, bash, directory

At the moment I found this one liner but I feel this could be even more simple. Maybe something im missing.

```
mv $PWD/sicky/infinity/foo $PWD/sicky/infinity/moo $PWD/sicky/infinity/tmp -t yicky/other-stuff
```

I am currently in the directory `~/icky` with the folders `~/icky/sicky` and `~/icky/yicky` within it.

It would take so long to go to each directory (foo, moo, tmp) and move that whole directory to `~/yicky/other-stuff` so I managed to get this one line to do it all. Could this be more simplified?

A secondary question: what if the directory `~/other-stuff` didn't exist yet? Could I make this one liner just a few characters longer to also create the directory I want the folders to go into?

Comment: Welcome! You wanto to move all the folders under `infinity/` or just some?

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten it a bit but the target needs to exist:

```
$ mkdir -p yicky/other-stuff; mv -t $_ sicky/infinity/{[mf]oo,tmp}
```